# fetch не выводит значения

Tags: php, база-данных, pdo, fetch

Есть функция

```
    public static function getMessageList($page = 1)
    {
        $page = intval($page);
        $offset = ($page - 1) * self::SHOW_BY_DEFAULT;

        $db = Db::getConnection(); 
        $sql = 'SELECT id, text, email, name, picture_path FROM message limit ' . self::SHOW_BY_DEFAULT . ' OFFSET ' . $offset;
        $result = $db->prepare($sql);

        $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $result->execute();
        $messageList = array();
        $i = 0; 
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $messageList[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
            $messageList[$i]['text'] = $row['text'];
            $messageList[$i]['email'] = $row['email'];
            $messageList[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
            $messageList[$i]['picture_path'] = $row['picture_path'];
            $i ++;
        }
        $db = null;
        return $messageList;
```

Проблема состоит в том, что вместо значений столбцов она выводит их названия

```
Number of message: 2

Text: :text

Email: :email

Name: :name

Picture:
```

Comment: fetch по аналогичной структуре кода работает верно, проблема не в нем. `$i ++;` здесь пробел лишний. Здесь можно использовать [fetchall](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: помимо `fetchAll` можно и просто `$msgs[] = $row`; зачем эти счетчики и поэлементное копирование? Тем не менее, сделайте `var_dump` и посмотрите что в массиве на выходе. проблема скорее в скрипте вывода, а не тут

Comment: Проблема была в скрипте ввода, спасибо за помощь